# How to remove View from superView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, xib, superview

I made an `xib` and showed it inside a view by following code.

```
    NSArray *xibContents = 
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"PickupAddressView"
            owner:self 
            options:nil];

    UIView *view = [xibContents objectAtIndex:0]; // Safer than objectAtIndex:0
    //UIView *subView=[view.subviews objectAtIndex:0];

    [view setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)];
    CGRect tempFrame=view.frame;
    tempFrame.size.width=300;//change acco. how much you want to expand
    tempFrame.size.height=350;
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.2];
    view.frame=tempFrame;
    //[UIView commitAnimations];
    [view setFrame:CGRectMake(10.0f, 90.0f, 300.0f, 350.0f)];
    [view setBackgroundColor:
      [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:
        [UIImage imageNamed:@"Register_bg"]]];
    [UIView commitAnimations];

    [view removeFromSuperview];
    [self.view addSubview:view];
```

I am using `UIStoryboard`, and made this `xib` and showed from following code.

How can I remove this view. I have a `UIButton`, whose `IBAction` is being called.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [remove UIView from superView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11355813/remove-uiview-from-superview)

Comment: your answer is a just clicked away..why dint you just tried to search..its easy http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11355813/remove-uiview-from-superview

Comment: It is working fine, but I can't remove this view

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Keep a weak reference to the view (either a property or an instance variable) and call `removeFromSuperview` like so:

```
[self.viewToRemove removeFromSuperview];
```

Answer (score 2):

It's too simple to remove any view from its super view just type

```
[yourview removeFromSuperview];
```

If you declaring view as a property, then use like below.

```
[self.yourview removeFromSuperview];
```

Comment: I didn't give downvote to you. If you know answer, just look at this question, if your answer is already provided by some one, just give upvote to them or just leave it. Or add some more point and post as answer